# Java Regex, Time pattern

Tags: java, regex

I´m trying to obtain a regular expression that cover this combinations:

```
1h 
2m 
3s 
1h 2m 
1h 2m 3s 
2m 3s
```

So far, I have the next one: **(\d+h\s?)?(\d+m\s?)?(\d+s\s?)**, but It doesn´t work fine.

Could anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?:\d+h)(?: \d+m(?: \d+s)?)?|\d+m(?: \d+s)?|\d+s
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\d+h)(?: \d+m(?: \d+s)?)?     match 1h or 1h 2m or 1h 2m 3s
\d+m(?: \d+s)?                   match 2m or 2m 3s
\d+s                             match 3s
```

Follow the link below for Java code demonstrating this regex against your sample inputs.

## Rextester

Comment: Your regex work in the link but not work in code check this [ideone](https://ideone.com/8BPyrP) any explication?

Comment: @YCF_L I believe I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful. Here we are using three combinations to prevent matching wrong patterns like `1h 3s`, as it is not mentioned in desired OP's question.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vE2BiE/2)

Optionally if you want to restrict digits to only two digits you can change this `\d+` to `\d{2}`

**Regex:** `^\d+[hms]$|^\d+[h]\s\d+[m](?:\s\d+[s])?$|^\d+m\s\d+s$`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `$` end of string.
>
> **3.** `\s` is for single space
>
> **4.** `^\d+[hms]$` one or more digit then either `h` , `m` and `s`
>
> **5.** `^\d+[h]\s\d+[m](?:\s\d+[s])?$` this will match `digits` then `h`, then `digits` then `m` and at-last `digits` then `s` which is optional.
>
> **6.** `^\d+m\s\d+s` this will match `digits` then `m` and then `digits` then `s`

Answer (score 0):

By grouping the interesting matches with |, You can match the valid portion of the string, with h, m, and s each captured in their own group so you can check if a particular line has a particular value. This is a great way to do optional matching with the completeness of full matching.

```
(?:\ ?(?:(\d+h)|(\d+m)|(\d+s)))+
```

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uupjhc/2))